# Get Navigation Menu for Experience Cloud User based on Audience

Tags: navigation, experience-cloud, navigation-menu, audience

I am attempting to create an LWC component for my orgs Experience cloud related to navigation. I'd like to get the navigation menu for the current user that is based on the audience they are in.

My hopes are to take that and create a customized nav bar to use on the Experience cloud site.

I don't see how to get the audience appropriate navigation menu items for a user though. Is there an API to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use branding Set in the theme menu